# Retract/Remove Solution - SharePoint 2010

Tags: retraction

How can I manually retract a solution, which is installed to a farm, using the SharePoint central administration interface?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Central Admin - System Settings - Manage Farm Solutions, pick your wsp and hit Retract, then Remove once it's done.

Comment: That did the trick !!

Answer (score 10):

## Using STSADM

1. Open command prompt and navigate to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN`
2. Use the stsadm command `stsadm -o retractsolution  -name solutionName.wsp -immediate`
3. and then remove the wsp `stsadm -o deletesolution -name solutionName.wsp`

## Using Powershell

1. Go to All Programs => Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products =>SharePoint 2010 Management Shell =>Run as administrator
2. `Uninstall-SPSolution -identity "solutionName.wsp"`
3. `Remove-SPSolution -identity "solutionName.wsp"`

Comment: Hi Deepu, thank you for this alternate ways to remove the solution :) +1